# Display specific posts on pages in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

In the website every product is a post, but when we add new products we want something like a newsletter, mostly like a post so in the sidebar of the home page you can see the new products or events of the month.

I'm using pages because I don't want to re-post a product on every new newsletter so I junt wanna display the posts inside the page.

In the products page I separate every product by category and sub-category but since I want to group specific post to publish them on the sidebar I think that pages was the best way to do it.

**Right now I'm using this code:**

```
<?php
$productos = new WP_Query(array(
'post__in'=> array(81, 83),
'orderby'=>'title',
'order'=>'ASC'
)
); if ($productos->have_posts()) : while ($productos->have_posts()) : $productos->the_post();
?>
```

It display the posts with the id of 81 and 83, I would like to show post by slug using 'name' as the codex says because is going to take some time to be checking the ids of the new post, instead of using the name of every new product but It doesn't work in array or I'm doing something wrong.

Now I will love to make something like this work

```
$names = get_post_meta($post->ID, "names", $single = true); 

$productos = new WP_Query(array(
'name'=> array($names),
'orderby'=>'title',
'order'=>'ASC'
)
);
```

So every time I publish a new page I just write the slugs of the posts that I want to include in the page in a custom field, as you can see I'm not very good with php but I trying to learn and I search a lot for something that could work before asking in here.

I try the ggis inline post plugin and although it works I need the id for every post I want to include and I will need to edit the plugin because I want a different order in the output of the post thats why I don't like to depend to much on plugins.

**Update:**

So I'm now looking if I can make this using shortcodes, right now I have this:

```
function producto_func($atts) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'nombre' => ''
    ), $atts));
    global $post;
    $pieza = get_page_by_title($nombre,OBJECT, 'post');
                echo '<h1>'. $pieza->ID . '</h1>';
}
add_shortcode('producto', 'producto_func');
enter code here
```

So I just enter the shortcode `[producto nombre="ff 244"]` in the page and it show its ID, and I can add any number of shortcodes depending on the number of post I need. 
But how can I show the entire content of the post.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find I solution using Shortcodes. 
So I put this on my functions.php page

```
function productos($atts, $content = null) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        "slug" => '',
        "query" => ''
    ), $atts));
    global $wp_query,$post;
    $temp = $wp_query;
    $wp_query= null;
    $wp_query = new WP_Query(array( 
    'name'=> $slug,
    ));
    if(!empty($slug)){
        $query .= '&name='.$slug;
    }
    if(!empty($query)){
        $query .= $query;
    }
    $wp_query->query($query);
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <?php while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
        <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
        <div><?php the_content() ?></div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php $wp_query = null; $wp_query = $temp;
    $content = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $content;
}
add_shortcode("producto", "productos");
```

And in my page template I just write [producto slug="MY-SLUG"] and that way I can display multiple post just with the slugs. Hope someone find this useful.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters):

Display **post** by slug:

> $query = new WP_Query( 'name=about-my-life' );

Display **page** by slug:

> $query = new WP_Query( 'pagename=contact' );

**UPDATE**

Try changing this:

```
'name'=> array($names),
```

To this:

```
'name'=> $names,
```

The 'name' - and 'pagename' - parameter does not take in an array. Only a string. A comma delimited list SHOULD give you what you need from within your Custom Fields titled "names", though I haven't tested this approach.

Also, thank you for using WP_Query instead of query_posts.

Comment: but I want to display posts on the page no another page that's why I'm using `'name'` and I need an array to display multiple posts.

Comment: I misunderstood this part: "I'm using pages because I don't want to re-post a product on every new newsletter so I junt wanna display the posts inside the page". If you're using Pages as a Shell for certain posts, then please review my update.

Comment: Thank you for your help I just try it but only accepts one value, if I put another slug on my custom field separated by a comma dosen't work. 
Is that what you mean by saying "A comma delimited list..."
I find a solution using Shortcodes that I'm going to post below

Comment: Shortcodes can work, along with a few other ways. Overall, it seems as if you've got it sorted.

Comment: Yes!, but thank you for the help. I don't have reputation so I can't answer right now.